# Recompiling Nginx

Tags: compilation, nginx

I have nginx running now on a live website, but I need to recompile it to add some extra features. The commands i use are.

```
make clean
./configure -- BLA BLA BLA
make
make install
```

Just to confirm, I don't need to stop nginx, until I run '`make install`' right? The 'make' command takes the longest, I just want to be 100% sure I dont need to stop Nginx sooner.

So to confirm, this would mean really just a second or two downtime.

```
make clean
./configure -- BLA BLA BLA
make
/etc/init.d/nginx stop
make install
/etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, make just do the linking and compilation, while make install will install it on the system

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have a downtime. You compile and replace the executable.
Then you trigger nginx to spawn a new master.
The process is explained here:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#upgrade

```
New Version - Master - start:
kill -s USR2 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`

Old Version - Worker - stop:
kill -s WINCH `cat /var/run/nginx.pid.oldbin`
Old Version - Master - stop:
kill -s QUIT `cat /var/run/nginx.pid.oldbin`
```

If you want to go back to the older version:

```
Old Version - Worker - start:
kill -s HUP `cat /var/run/nginx.pid.oldbin`
New Version - Master - stop:
kill -s QUIT `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
```

If you get an error that the file cannot be replaced your compile options are wrong.

```
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx
```

Comment: When does this take place in the `make clean`, `./configure`, `make` lifecycle?

Comment: @MajorProductionsLLC After `make install`. The old master process only lives in RAM as far as i understood because the executable is replaced before spawning a new master process. Once the "old version master" is stopped, the replace process is finished and can't be undone until recompile etc.